# Numpy bug using .any()?

Tags: numpy

I'm having the following error using NumPy:

```
>>> distance = 0.9014179933248182
>>> min_distance = np.array([0.71341723, 0.07322284])
>>> distance < min_distance
array([False, False])
```

which is right, but when I try:

```
>>> distance < min_distance.any()
True
```

which is obviously wrong, since there is no number in 'min_distance' smaller than 'distance'

What is going on here? I'm using NumPy on Google Colab, on version '1.17.3'.

Comment: That `any` just looks for any value not zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst numpy bugs are common, this is not one.  Note that `min_distance.any()` returns a boolean result.  So in this expression:

```
distance < min_distance.any()
```

you are comparing a float with a boolean, which unfortunately works, because of a comedy of errors:

- `bool` is a subclass of `int`
- `True` is equal to `1`
- floats are comparable with integers.

E.g.

```
>>> 0.9 < True
True
>>> 1.1 < True
False
```

What you wanted instead:

```
>>> (distance < min_distance).any()
False
```

Answer (score 2):

try `(distance < min_distance).any()`